# youtube-dl 'youtube-dl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables, youtube

I have already added the path to environment path variable.

[image: Screenshot of path environment variable]

But when I tried to execute it through cmd . I am getting the error

> 'youtube-dl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Your didn't troubleshoot this. Your mistake would apply to  any or  pretty much any exe file not already in the path. (i.e. to any exe not in the path properly / put into the path like you did there = not in the path!). And infact you said yourself you are meant to add the directory to the path,  You are meant to add directories to the path environment variable. Look at all of them that wre there before you tried making that funny entry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not add specific programs to your path, you add the folder containing your programs.

You need to remove the `youtube-dl.exe` from the end of highlighted line.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks @mokubai

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder somewhere (except from `C:\Windows\system32` or `wherever-your-system32-is`)

Name it whatever you like,

eg.

```javascript
C:\youtube-dl
```

Then move the `youtube-dl.exe` inside it

```
C:\youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe
```

Now, when adding it in your `PATH` it `should` be the `name of the folder`

eg.

[image: Sample path]

Then, please, close any terminal/cmd that is/are open before trying it out.

In summary, the `path` (`folder directory`) to the `.exe` is needed not the `.exe` file when declaring it in your environment variables.

This is just to elaborate Mokubai's answer.